# Getting an error with my parameterized query string Microsoft SQL Server, ASP Classic

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, asp-classic

So I am working with a safe (or at least more safe) way to insert data into my SQL Server database. The data is being retrieved from a form (all in ASP classic).

Though when I try to output write my update statement I am getting an error, so I am guessing there is something wrong with my parameters but I don't quite know what it is.

**The FORM**

So the form contains some input fields and are given to the query, as well as 4 remaining fields that are not given as input fields (date today, date tomorrow, status and some string (d000 code) which is related to the relation / company).

When the form is submitted I add a protection to the input with a special function:

```vb
'----Protecting user input----
    Function ProtectSQL(SQLString)
    SQLString = Replace(SQLString, "'", "&#39;") ' replace single Quotes with Double Quotes
    SQLString = Replace(SQLString, ">", "&gt;") ' replace > with &gt;
    SQLString = Replace(SQLString, "<", "&lt;") ' replace < with &lt;
    SQLString = Replace(SQLString, "(","&#40;") ' replace ( with &#40;
    SQLString = Replace(SQLString, ")","&#41;") ' replace ) with &#41;
    SQLString = Replace(SQLString, "&", "&amp;")
    SQLString = Replace(SQLString, "%", "&#37;")
    SQLString = Replace(SQLString, vblf,"<br />") 
    SQLString = Trim(SQLString)
    ProtectSQL = SQLString
    End Function
```

The data from the forms is then collected with the extra protect function:

```vb
'Getting INSERT DATA
    FormAutomatisering = ProtectSQL(request.Form("automatisering"))
    FormProbleem = ProtectSQL(request.Form("probleem"))
    FormNaam = ProtectSQL(request.Form("Name"))
    FormEmail = ProtectSQL(request.Form("EMail"))       
    FormOnderwerp = ProtectSQL(request.Form("Onderwerp"))
    FormBeschrijving = ProtectSQL(request.Form("Beschrijving"))
    FormUrgentie = ProtectSQL(request.Form("hoog"))
    FormRecode = ProtectSQL(outputRecode)

'---Submit and end date---
    sToday=now()
    sTomorrow=dateadd("d","1",sToday)
```

So the `sToday`, `sTomorrow` and `FormRecode` are self-generated fields for the database (`FormRecode` is a function where the email domain is being retrieved from the inserted email and its then being linked to a relation code).

**The INSERT query**

After getting all the necessary fields I can use them in my `INSERT` statement.

```vb
OpenConn con 

    con.commandtext="INSERT INTO tblMMMemos (Datum, EindDatum, becode, recode, Categorie, Onderwerp, Omschrijving, Status, Name, Ontvanger, Contact, RelatieType)values('" & year(sToday)&"-" & month(sToday) & "-" & day(sToday) & " " & time() & "','" & year(sTomorrow)&"-" & month(sTomorrow) & "-" & day(sTomorrow) & " " & time() & "',?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    'Date given directly in the query
    'EndDate givin directly in the query
    con.Parameters.Append con.CreateParameter("@Becode", adChar, adParamInput, 3, FormBecode)
    con.Parameters.Append con.CreateParameter("@Recode", adChar, adParamInput, 8, FormRecode)
    con.Parameters.Append con.CreateParameter("@Categorie", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 10, FormCategorie)
    con.Parameters.Append con.CreateParameter("@Onderwerp", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, FormOnderwerp)
    con.Parameters.Append con.CreateParameter("@Omschrijving", adLongVarChar, adParamInput, , FormBeschrijving)
    con.Parameters.Append con.CreateParameter("@Status", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 10, FormStatus)
    con.Parameters.Append con.CreateParameter("@Name", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50, FormNaam)
    con.Parameters.Append con.CreateParameter("@Ontvanger", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50, FormOntvanger)
    con.Parameters.Append con.CreateParameter("@Contact", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, FormNaam)
    con.Parameters.Append con.CreateParameter("@RelatieType", adChar, adParamInput, 1, FormRelatieType)
    'set rschTicket = con.execute

    CloseConn con
```

Don't mind the fields in the update query not being exactly the same as the ones of the form, some form input fields need to run a if statement (for example radio buttons) and are given a variable to it and that is why some of them differ.

So does anyone has a clue what is going wrong?

**----UPDATE----**

So the error message has been traced and I am getting the following message:

```
Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in 
conflict with one another.
```

On this line:

```
con.Parameters.Append con.CreateParameter("@Becode", adChar, adParamInput, 3, FormBecode)
```

So things I tried to fix it:

1. Removed the date fields that are given directly (for testing it works without them)
2. There was one ? to much and removed it.
3. Replaced all the ? with the matching @ parameters in the query
4. Try'd to replace the first line (line of the error) with a other append line (also changed the order in the query).
5. Added the command object.

Though, all these changes weren't effective and I am still getting the same error.

Also good to know is that i checked the datatypes (and length of them) in my Microsoft SQL server table and they are a match, compared the ADO datatypes to the SQL datatypes on http://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_datatypes.asp.

**----UPDATE 2----**

Managed to fix it myself by losing the entire parameter model and replacing it with a much simpler one:

```
chTicket.Parameters(0).value = FormBecode
            chTicket.Parameters(1).value = FormRecode
            chTicket.Parameters(2).value = FormCategorie
            chTicket.Parameters(3).value = FormOnderwerp
            chTicket.Parameters(4).value = FormBeschrijving
            chTicket.Parameters(5).value = FormStatus
            chTicket.Parameters(6).value = FormNaam
            chTicket.Parameters(7).value = FormOntvanger
            chTicket.Parameters(8).value = FormNaam
            chTicket.Parameters(9).value = FormUrgentie
            chTicket.Parameters(10).value = FormRelatieType
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Well, I am working in Notepad++ so the errors are displaying directly on the web. The error I am getting is just a general one on submit of the form: 500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: How to enable detailed error messages - http://www.chestysoft.com/asp-error-messages.asp

Comment: @roryap Updated the original post with the error message and self made fixes (that don't work).

Comment: What is the *exact* data type of `becode` in the `tblMMMemos` table?

Comment: Its a simple string (always 3 letters). Though I managed to fix the problem. See update. Thank you anyway!